# Why localhost webview content does not enable TalkBack in Android

Tags: android, webview, accessibility, talkback, accessibilityservice

In my Android application I have loaded a web content in WebView.After enabling TalkBack feature the webview contents respond to user touching and it speaks the webview content.But when I loaded a localhost website in WebView, TalkBack does not respond to user touchings.It does not speak the WebView content.How to make enable TalkBack even for localhost webview contents?

Comment: Is Javascript enabled in the WebView? Does the application request the Internet permission and does the device have network connectivity? What version of Android?

Comment: Yes, I enabled Javascript in the WebView.I want to access the local hosted website. So I connected the localhost and android device via Wi-Fi hotspot.Android version is 4.2

Comment: But I don't share the Internet through Wi-Fi hotspot.Is that essential?

Comment: Unfortunately the answer is yes on versions prior to L Preview. WebView used to use a JS-based screen reader that required an internet connection to load (unless it happened to be cached, but this is unlikely). L Preview and later have a native implementation.

Comment: Please tell me what's the matter with my application?. My app's android:minSdkVersion="14" and android:targetSdkVersion="19".Android version of my device is 4.2.2.

Comment: Thank you alanv.After sharing internet connection through wifi hotspot it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prior to Android L Preview, WebViews with Javascript enabled required an internet connection for spoken accessibility to work correctly. This is because WebView relied on a JS-based screen reader (ChromeVox) that may not always be available in WebView cache.